# Php json: Pegar valores específicos de uma API em Json e exibi-las através de um script php

Tags: php, json, api, rest

Estou trabalhando com uma API e gostaria de "pegar" alguns valores da mesma que esta em formato JSON. A princípio pesquisei algumas questões similares a minha, mas infelizmente ainda não consegui encontrar um meio certo para fazer isso:

1. [Caminho json para pegar valor de api](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/171786/caminho-json-para-pegar-valor-de-api)
2. [Como pegar um JSON, a partir de uma URL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180265/como-pegar-um-json-a-partir-de-uma-url)
3. [Pegar resultado JSON com php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166775/pegar-resultado-json-com-php)
4. [Como imprimir um valor específico de um JSON em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272631/como-imprimir-um-valor-especifico-de-um-json-em-php)

No caso estou usando o seguinte código Curl em php para pegar os dados vindos da API:

```php
<?php

$token = "TOKEN_PROD";

$ch = curl_init('URL_DA_API');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Content-Type: application/json',
   'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
   ));

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

echo $data;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Quando o script acima é executado, o comando **echo $data;** exibe os seguintes valores vindos da API:

```
{
   "paging":{
      "total":1,
      "limit":30,
      "offset":0
   },
   "results":[
      {
         "metadata":{
            
         },
         "corporation_id":null,
         "operation_type":"regular_payment",
         "fee_details":[
            
         ],
         "notification_url":null,
         "date_approved":null,
         "money_release_schema":null,
         "payer":{
            "entity_type":null,
            "identification":{
               
            },
            "phone":{
               
            },
            "operator_id":null,
            "last_name":null,
            "id":"300287182",
            "type":"guest",
            "first_name":null,
            "email":null
         },
         "transaction_details":{
            "total_paid_amount":10,
            "acquirer_reference":null,
            "installment_amount":0,
            "financial_institution":null,
            "net_received_amount":0,
            "overpaid_amount":0,
            "external_resource_url":"https://www.mercadopago.com/mlb/payments/ticket/helper?payment_id=10598109806&payment_method_reference_id=9640456199&caller_id=307652082&hash=c70230f6-567c-4f1f-9f40-0a43213df8f6e",
            "payable_deferral_period":null,
            "payment_method_reference_id":"9642476599",
            "verification_code":"9644359199"
         },
         "statement_descriptor":null,
         "call_for_authorize_id":null,
         "installments":1,
         "pos_id":null,
         "external_reference":null,
         "date_of_expiration":"2020-10-18T22:59:59.000-04:00",
         "charges_details":[
            
         ],
         "id":10590861806,
         "payment_type_id":"ticket",
         "barcode":{
            "content":"23798712200000010003380260964249919230973330"
         },
         "order":{
            "id":"1880577004",
            "type":"mercadopago"
         },
         "counter_currency":null,
         "brand_id":null,
         "status_detail":"pending_waiting_payment",
         "differential_pricing_id":null,
         "additional_info":{
            "ip_address":"345.24.881.02",
            "nsu_processadora":null,
            "available_balance":null
         },
         "live_mode":true,
         "marketplace_owner":null,
         "card":{
            
         },
         "integrator_id":null,
         "status":"pending",
         "transaction_amount_refunded":0,
         "transaction_amount":10,
         "description":"Plano Trimestral",
         "money_release_date":null,
         "merchant_number":null,
         "refunds":[
            
         ],
         "authorization_code":null,
         "captured":true,
         "collector_id":587663946,
         "merchant_account_id":null,
         "taxes_amount":0,
         "date_last_updated":"2020-10-15T18:27:46.000-04:00",
         "coupon_amount":0,
         "store_id":null,
         "date_created":"2020-10-15T18:27:46.000-04:00",
         "acquirer_reconciliation":[
            
         ],
         "sponsor_id":null,
         "shipping_amount":0,
         "issuer_id":null,
         "payment_method_id":"bolbradesco",
         "binary_mode":false,
         "platform_id":null,
         "deduction_schema":null,
         "processing_mode":"aggregator",
         "currency_id":"BRL",
         "shipping_cost":0
      }
   ]
}
```

Entretanto, conforme a resposta JSON acima da API, gostaria que o script PHP apenas retornasse alguns objetos conforme abaixo:

1. id
2. date_created
3. total_payment_amount
4. payment_method_id
5. status_detail

Tentei inserir o código abaixo no script php para ter uma ideia de como eu poderia solucionar esta questão:

```
$json = json_decode($data);
echo $json->results->id[0];
```

No caso como posso fazer para que o script php apenas exiba os valores que mencionei acima? Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando decodificado **results** é um array. Então acredito que deva ficar assim:

```
$json = json_decode($data);
echo $json->results[0]->id;
echo $json->results[0]->date_created;
echo $json->results[0]->transaction_details->total_paid_amount;
echo $json->results[0]->payment_method_id;
echo $json->results[0]->status_detail;
```

Quando se trada de manipulação de json decodificado eu recomendo dar um `var_dump` no `$json` para visualizar melhor.

Comment: Olá Renê, obrigado pelo retorno. Deu certo o seu script. Muito obrigado mesmo. Só mais uma última dúvida. No caso se eu quiser usar um foreach para que apareça todos os resultados correspondentes ficaria mais ou menos assim? ** $decode = json_decode( $data, true ); foreach ( $decode["id"]["date_created"] as $valor){$id = $valor[""];echo $id;}**... Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Consegui implementar assim e funcionou:  $decode = json_decode( $data, TRUE );
 foreach ( $decode["results"] as $valor){
  echo 'Id:'.$valor["id"].PHP_EOL.'<br>';
  echo 'Rel.:'.$valor["date_created"].PHP_EOL.'<br>';
  echo 'Rel.:'.$valor["status_details"].PHP_EOL.'<br>';
  echo PHP_EOL;
 }
Valeu Renê. Obrigado.